# how to show every each of the bootstrapped data / sampled data in random forest sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

from what i understand about random forest alogirthm is that the algorithm randomly samples the original dataset to build a new sampled/bootstrapped dataset. the sampled dataset then turned into decision trees.

in scikit learn, you can visualize each individual trees in random forest. but my question is, How to show the sampled/bootstrapped dataset from each of those trees?
i want to see the features and the rows of data used to build each individual trees.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to see the bootstrapped rows (samples) of your data, as this is a random process. Neither do I think it is of much importance, if the algorithm trained well.

Nevertheless, for the features: In your visualization of the tree you might already see which features were used by the splits that have been done. But you can also access them directly via the attribute `feature_names_in_` (see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html)) for each DecisionTree in the forest, e.g.

```
print(rf.estimators_[0].feature_names_in_)
```

If your feature names in the data have not been defined as given in the documentation, a workaround is to use the `feature_importances_` (see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.feature_importances_)) as a proxy instead - the features that were unused obviously have an importance of 0. You can contrast this with the number of `max_features_` that you define for the training to see if you caught all.

Comment: thankyou so much for the answer!

i tried the code, it showed an error code like this:
"AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'feature_names_in_"

what can i do to fix this?

Comment: Does the other method work for you (using the feature_importances_)?

Comment: Usually, the error should not appear if you pass the feature names with the training data X (for example as a DataFrame) while training the classifier. You can try this. It might be, that this information is still not passed on to the single trees in the classifier (I found this error existing in quite some questions), leading to the missing attribute. For the whole forest, this attribute will exist. So, either looking at the graph or the feature_importances might be the way to go.